# error de protocolo 0x1104

Tags: windows, redes, rdp

Saludos

Estoy tratando de conectarme a un servidor Windows Server 2008 R2 por RDP con otra maquina con Windows 7. El problema es que cuando intento hacerlo me aparece el mensaje de: Esta sesion se desconectara debido a un error de protocolo en el cliente codigo 0x1104.

Crei que era un problema del puerto 3389 pero verifique que ese puerto se encuentra abierto. Cual podra ser el problema???

de antemano gracias

Answer (score 1):

En varios casos había reportes que el error que mencionas aparece con incompatibilidades en el estilo visual entre los sistemas.

Si es el caso, el remedio es de apagar la opción de estilos visuales en las opciones de tu cliente RDP.

Desconozco los menus en español, pero deberías encontrar la opción en `opciones(?)->experiencia(?)->estilos_visuales(?)`.

Por favor, sería amable si podrías confirmar como se llega a la opción en un sistema en español cuando lo encuentras.

Comment: Buen día tengo el mismo problema, y no se soluciono apagando la opción de estilos, sr stefan nolde, sabe que otra cosa puede ser?

Comment: Usas exactamente la misma combinación de sistemas? En casos de Server 2003 existe [este problema conocido](https://support.microsoft.com/es-es/help/898060/network-connectivity-between-clients-and-servers-may-fail-after-you-install-security-update-ms05-019-or-windows-server-2003-service-pack-1)